is there any custom way to separate prisma schema into multiple files and gether them into single file?
prisma has released version 5.15.0 which support prismaSchemaFolder preview feature.But
Preview features in Prisma are new features that are not yet considered production-ready.
They are released to gather feedback from users and to allow users to test them before they become generally available.
These features are typically stable but may still have minor bugs, and users are encouraged to provide feedback to help improve them.
is there any custom way to separate prisma schema into multiple files and gether them into single file?
i tried prismix ,but the thing i came to know that i have to add an empty model whenever i need to relate that model with another
model Posts {
    id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
    title      String
    content    String
    account_id Int
    account    Account @relation(fields: [account_id], references: [id])

    @@map("posts")
}

model Account {
    id     String
    posts  Post[]
}

here account is in another file but need to redefined in order to create the relation with posts
